# How to give a command for the next iteration

Tags: python, for-loop

Im trying to write a code to say that if a condition is met of a value in a list then in the next iteration make that value a different one. the problem is i dont know what the code is to tell python to do it in the next iteration
my code.

```
list_ = [4, 5, 6, 6, 4, 5]

for i in range(0, 10):
    for j in range(0, len(list_)):
        if list_[j] == 5:
            if list_[(j-1) % len(list)] == 4:
                list_[j][i+1] = 3
```

but this doesnt work as i get a int' object does not support item assignment error. also i know some of the indentation maybe wrong its because i struggled to put them into here

Comment: You need colons after `if` statements, and please fix your indents (four spaces).  What is `e`?  Show `list` (preferrably renamed to a non-builtin name, e.g. `list_`)

Comment: sorry ive added the colons and changed the list name i cant add four spaces as this doesnt work for me for some reason

Comment: Can you show a sample of your list, and what you want the code do do at each iteration? A detailed explanation of each expected step is necessary here because your intent is unclear otherwise.

Comment: i want the code to check if a value is a 5 and if it is then check if the number before it is a 4 and if it is then in the next iteration change that 5 to a 3

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will suffice, building a new list according to your logic:

```
list_ = [4, 5, 6, 6, 4, 5]

lst = []
for i, x in enumerate(list_):
    if (x == 5) and (list_[i-1] == 4) and (i-1 > 0):
        lst.append(3)
    else:
        lst.append(x)
lst   
# [4, 3, 6, 6, 4, 3]
```

As a list comprehension:

```
[3 if (x == 5) and (list_[i-1] == 4) and (i-1 > 0) else x for i, x in enumerate(list_)]
# [4, 3, 6, 6, 4, 3]
```

The `(i-1 > 0)` prevents searching the end if `5` is in the first position.

---

Three main pythonic themes of this implementation:

1. create a new iterable instead of mutating it
2. `enumerate` an iterable to reduce the use of indices
3. use booleans to chain conditionals rather than nesting conditionals

Answer (score 0):

Your exact expected result is not so clear, but anyway I suggest you this solution that seems solving your problem:

```
list_ = [4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 5]

for j in range(0, len(list_)):
    if (list_[j] == 5) and (list_[j-1] == 4):
        list_[j] = 3

print(list_)
```

Note: on the first iteration, `list_[j-1]` refers to the last element of the list.